# LiveReload of Vaadin + Spring Boot in Firefox don't work

Tags: spring-boot, firefox, vaadin, vaadin14

The LiveReload feature doesn't work with Firefox. I've setup a Vaadin 14 + Spring Boot 2.4 App according the Tutorial and install the AddOn LiveReload in Firefox 86.0 (64-Bit) for MacOs. Spring Boot has the devtools added and LiveReload enabled, the log mentioned LiveReload server is running on port 35729. If I modify any java sources, the Spring Boot App restarts but the html page in FF isn't reloaded. Only a small notification "Vaadin development mode initialized" is visible in the lower right corner of the FF windows. In Google Chrome (Version 89.0.4389.72 (x86_64)) for MacOs everything work as expected.

How can I enabled LiveReload for Firefox too ?

Kind regards Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: after reducing the time needed for reloading the spring boot app dramatically by using the property `vaadin.whitelisted-packages`, also those strange LiveReload problem has gone. Maybe its linked to [this issue](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/8020) mentioned a race condition for the FF liveReload add-on.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you mark your solution as accepted? Thanks in advance!